# Unable to post Chinese characters?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, formatting

I just wrote [an answer to a question about Japan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52723/do-bus-stations-have-names-in-english-in-tokyo/52724#52724), but it's rejecting all my attempts to enter any *kanji* (Chinese characters used in Japan) like [this guy](http://redfinchjapanese.com/?action=kanji_dictionary&kanji=376) with this error message:

[image: "Body cannot contain 'X'" popup message]

Hiragana (すし) and full-width numbers (０１) appear to be OK.  What's going on?

Comment: Let's see if they work in a comment… oh, they don't either! http://i.imgur.com/UpDNx46.png

Comment: I get a 500 Internal Server Error in the console when I try to post any [CJK ideographs](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U4E00.pdf) (I don't think it makes any distinction as to whether it's hanza, kanji, or hanja, so it's not limited to Japanese; the code points are the same for Korean and Chinese).

Comment: Based on [this post on meta.se](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261609/not-all-utf-8-characters-supported/261622#comment857666_261611), looks like we should now be on the allowed list. Can you test and confirm?

Comment: 唔該 It looks like TSE is whitelisted from the ban.

Comment: Did you mean "kana", not "katakana"?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Meant "hiragana", fixed; thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**[A-ha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261609).** @jmac says

> We were getting a deluge of Chinese-language spam, and it was evolving so we just blocked Chinese characters. At some point in the future we will re-enable Chinese.

Apparently, it means some [usernames can't be entered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263416) either. @snailboat has found [a workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261622).

Comment: Let's hope there's no future deluge of English-language spam.

Comment: They seem to have reenabled Chinese text and now the spam is back.  I left a detailed comment at the "A-ha" link above, but basically it's a Chinese service to get fake US college diplomas.